# IE8 data island (xml tag) not setting datafld based on datasrc

Tags: xml, data-binding, internet-explorer-8

I have to make changes to a legacy web page that uses the IE xml tag to specify a data island for subsequent data binding for various HTML elements via assignment of datasrc and datafld attributes.

When I open the *.htm file locally using IE8, none of the data fields that should have been bound are displayed. The same happens when I'm trying compatibility view for IE7.

When I take the files to another PC and open them with IE8, all the data fields are displayed as expected. I assume there is some configuration difference between the IE8 browsers on the two PCs, but I can't figure out what.

Does anyone have an idea what may be happening and how I can get IE8 to display the data fields on the original PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX was not enabled, duh